# Creating a conditional to validate Email addresses

Tags: regex, bash, cat

I have used a preg_match based 'regex' in a php script that I use.  The regex is `^[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}$`

How can I incorporate this in a bash conditional to test Email addresses for basic structure?  My email address is in a file called 'email'. (It is looped through as required). Like `if [cat email | '/^[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}$/' ]; then {`
or whatever.  I have no idea how to write this.  Can anyone help...

Comment: What do you mean by 'bash conditional'? Please clarify thanks,

Comment: A conditional like if [ TRUE ]; then {  something else something else.  The conditional being in lieu of TRUE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your regular expression and adapting it to `bash` to test an address held in the variable `email`:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $email =~ ^[[:alnum:]_.-]+@[[:alnum:]_.-]+\.[[:alpha:]]{2,6}$ ]]
then
    echo "Good address"
else
    echo "Bad address"
fi
```

Notes:

- this uses the `[[...]]` construct so an ordinary POSIX shell won't do: `bash` or better is required.
- The `=~` operator matches a string, in this case the email address, to a POSIX Extended Regular Expression.
- The actual spec for email addresses, (have a look at [RFC5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322)), is very complex  (see this sample but outdated [regex](http://ex-parrot.com/%7Epdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)) and your regex is only an approximation.

Comment: Thank you.  If I used your code how would I add the underscore, as you suggest, to it?  Or is it there already?

Comment: It your Notes do you mean +~ or =~ in note 2?

Comment: @user3386373  Thanks for catching the `+~` typo: I just fixed it.  Also, the underscore is added already.  I was leaving plus, percent, and other characters to your discretion.